# Why does my Application.Exit(); call fail?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding in C#, and I have an exit button on my form that calls
    Application.Exit();
Now most of the time the button works without an issue at all, but occasionally the program doesn't seem to recognize that the program is being told to close, as if the button doesn't work any longer? There are no errors being thrown it just seems that the button doesn't register that its being clicked, even though visibly it shows the button being pressed. The most recent issue with the exit button came after the program sat for 20 minutes and then I told it to exit. Thanks for any thoughts on the matter.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint into the button click event handler, does it hit ALWAYS?

Comment: Your code for the button click and any relevant Form events would be useful.

Comment: We would be able to give you better feedback if you posted the relevant code.

Comment: Could you post your event handling and subscription code? If you put a breakpoint in the handler when the button "stops working", is it hit?

Comment: You just threw us in the middle of the Amazon jungle with a pair of glasses as a compass.

Comment: We understand your problem, but we cant help out, unless we can see what the code is

Answer (score 3):

Application.Exit() does not necessarily force an application to exit immediately.  Here's a nice breakdown of Application.Exit() vs Enivronment.Exit():

http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

And of course the MSDN official word:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx

Other than those thoughts, we'd need to see the code to give advise on what precisely is going on with your application.